# How to search through a string and output the first 3 lines of a string

Tags: python

I am currently trying to read show commands from a network device, and get just the first 3 lines of the show commands and store them just in case something happens during this script, and treat them as a rollback object.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to search through inputs of a large string and just output the first three lines and disregard everything else.

*Edited*2* hopefully easier to read.

```
gig1 = '''interface GigabitEthernet0/1
description
bandwidth
ip address x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
ip access-group xxx in
ip nbar protocol-discovery
ip flow monitor input
ip flow monitor output
ip flow egress
duplex auto
speed auto
service-policy output QOS-PARENT-OUT
'''

class Comparison():

    def CurrentConfig(interface):

        cmd = '{} '.format(interface)

        print(cmd)
        split_str = cmd.split('\n')
        first_3_lines = split_str[:3]
        return (first_3_lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = { 'interfaces': gig1 }

    interface = config['interfaces']
    output_list = []output = Comparison.CurrentConfig(interface)
    output_list.append(output)

    currentconfig = output

    print(currentconfig)
```

Output: 
    ['interface GigabitEthernet0/1', 'description', 'bandwidth']

However I want the output to not be in a list format, is this where you add the .format(currentconfig) command?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is very unclear. What does all that code have to do with "just output[ing] the first three lines and disregard[ing] everything else"? Do you want just the first three "lines" that would be *printed* if the string were printed? What is that "output" you show (it does not include the print statement in your code)? Please clarify by reading and following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I only want to get the following information and keep it:

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description 
 bandwidth 

everything else that i get from the output, i could care less about, since this is just making changes to the above.

Comment: You did not answer the majority of my questions. I suggest that you edit your question to handle the issues I raised, which will clarify your question and make it more likely for you to get good answers.

Comment: So im confused since im new to the flow of python, I dont understand why the information im pulling is being used as a list, because doing a fresh python script doesn't behave the same way as getting information from a device. So im not sure exactly how to make it easier for other to read.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Is correct. Try to hone in on the piece you need help with. That said, assuming the output you've shown always has that same pattern, you might -- in a pinch (i.e. temporarily) -- try replacing your final `print` statement with something like this: `print(currentconfig.partition('\n ip address')[0])`. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Got it to work thanks to all your help guys

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return the first three lines of a multi-line string:

```py
test_str = '''this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
some other lines
more lines
blah blah blah


last line
'''

split_str = test_str.split('\n')
first_3_lines = split_str[:3]
```

If this doesn't help, can I suggest you make a *minimal* example of code showing the problem you are having as the above snippet is quite long and has lots of parts that are irrelevant to your stated problem.

Comment: Thanks I used your input but changed [:3] to [:4] because Cisco adds an empty char, but its only outputting in my example 
inte

So for your example would be This